# How to remove Blazor code block background color?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor

I am trying out blazor webassembly app and on Visual Studio 2019 Dark theme, code blocks are highlighted with dark gray color which makes it harder to read, is there a way to remove it without switching to lighter theme?

I tried to find "Razor" and "Blazor" Under Options > font & colors

[image]

Comment: 2 years later and this still looks horrible. I wonder why they never changed it. It's just very stressful to look at imo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oddly enough I had to google this yesterday, as I hated the lack of contrast!

It's set under `Tools => Options` menu, in `Fonts and Colors`:
[image: Fonts and Colors options page]

I set my background to match the editor background (which is RGB 30,30,30) so the backgrounds match:

[image: Background color settings]

Comment: Thank you, I  also found out making it default also works, default picks up that dark color,

Comment: A quick side note that the updated Razor Editor in VS2019 preview will do away with this